# PostgreSQL Trigger takes 5 seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

i have a MediaStore Database on Postgres where tried to make a trigger which Updates the average Rating of a Product if a new review is inserted.

The Problem is: If I insert a review now, it takes more than **5 seconds**.

Im not really into Databases so i thought of asking you people here :)

The DDL of the two relevant tables are:

```
create table review
(
    review_id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
    rating     integer not null CHECK (rating BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
    helpful    integer not null CHECK (helpful >= 0),
    reviewDate date,
    benutzer varchar(255),
    summary varchar(255),
    comment text,
    produkt_id bigint NOT NULL references produkt ON DELETE CASCADE
);
create table produkt
(
    produkt_id       bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
    asin     varchar(255) unique NOT NULL,
    titel varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    rating   double precision,
    bild     varchar(1000),
    verkaufsrang integer
);
```

And the Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_rating()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE produkt
    SET rating =
      (SELECT AVG(rating) AS rating 
       FROM review 
       GROUP BY produkt_id 
       Having review.produkt_id = new.produkt_id)
  WHERE produkt_id = new.produkt_id;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_rating
    AFTER INSERT ON review
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_rating();
```

Does somebody have a solution which reduces the Time of the Insert?

Comment: You are computing average of all reviews for a product on each insert. Depending on how many reviews are for that product this is bound to become slower and slower over time. I would consider updating the average reviews periodically (once an hour?) instead of doing it on every single insert.

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe your indexes.  An index on `review (produkt_id, rating)` could help a lot if you don't have one already.  If you had columns in produkt for sum and count, then you could just compute the new average without needing to traverse the entire set in review for that produkt_id.  You might have a problem with concurrency, but that could be a problem with your current one too.

Comment: The thing is: If i do a query with the exact same statements it takes approx half a second or less to do it. Thats whats confusing me. But Ill try to create an index. Thanks :)